# Google Map Library Places and Geometry working together in one HTML page

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I try to make a page that calculate distance and route between two location. These location are inputted by user with auto-complete function from google map in its textbox. As per my knowledge it require 2 library to be working, geolocation and places. However my program not working as expected, when both of library are imported.
It just working when either places or geometry were disabled.

my imported javascript library as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places,geometry"></script>
```

JS:

```
var map;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize() {
    // Buat untuk draggable
    var rendererOptions = {
        draggable: true
    }
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    var jakarta = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.195456, 106.822229);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: jakarta
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));

    start = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('start')), {
        types: ['geocode']
    });
    end = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('end')), {
        types: ['geocode']
    });

}

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
            position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            start.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
            geolocation));
            end.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
            geolocation));
        });
    }
}

function calcRoute(start, end) {

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        provideRouteAlternatives: true,
        avoidHighways: true,
        avoidTolls: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            // Resize the map canvas to accomodate
            // the textual directions panel
            map_canvas.style.width = '70%';
            directionsPanel.style.display = 'inline';
            // Request map resize.
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

            // display the directions
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            // Display the distance:
            document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + " Meter";

            // Display the duration:
            document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " Detik";

            //  Define perhitungan ongkos
            var subTotal = 0.0;
            var hargaPerMeter = 3;
            var argoMinimum = 15000;
            var jarakMinimum = 5000;
            var jarakAntar = parseInt(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);

            if (jarakAntar < jarakMinimum) {
                subTotal = argoMinimum;
                document.getElementById('ongkos').innerHTML = " Rp. " + subTotal.toFixed(2);
            } else {
                // Hitung ongkos berdasarkan jarak
                subTotal += (jarakAntar * hargaPerMeter);
                document.getElementById('ongkos').innerHTML = " Rp. " + subTotal.toFixed(2);
            }
        } else {
            alert('Kesalahan pada alamat !');
        }

    });

    function hitungOngkos() {
        var subTotal = 0.0;
        var hargaPerMeter = 3000;
        var dropOffCharge = 2.50;
        var overTwoPassengerCharge = 2.00;
        var jarakAntar = (document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value) / 1000;
        var passengers = Number(document.getElementById("passengers").value);

        // kalo goncengan, tambahan orang kena Rp. 20.000
        if (passengers > 2) {
            subTotal = overTwoPassengerCharge * (passengers - 2);
        }

        // Hitung ongkos berdasarkan jarak
        subTotal += parseInt(jarakAntar * 5) * hargaPerMeter;
        subTotal += dropOffCharge;
        // cetak ongkos pada element div. toFixed masukan receh pada perhitungan
        document.getElementById('ongkos').innerHTML = " $" + subTotal.toFixed(0);
    }
}

/*
 * Show the textual directions panel, resize the map canvas
 * trigger resize event on map, and compute the directions             
 * Note that start and end corresponds to the input id of
 * the controls
 */
function showDirectionsPanelandCalculate() {
    if (start.value.length == 0 || end.value.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    calcRoute(start.value, end.value);

}

/*
 * Hide the textual directions panel resize map
 * canvas to original size, trigger resize on
 * map.  You can also recalculate directions if
 * desired.
 */
function hideDirectionsPanel() {

    map_canvas.style.width = '100%';
    directionsPanel.style.display = 'none';
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width:950px;
}
/* Controls that takes the start/end address.
        */
 #controls {
    background-color: lightgray;
    font-size: 11px;
    position:fixed;
    /*  bottom:-0px; */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    left:5px;
    border:1px solid darkgray;
    padding:5px;
    z-index:10000;
}
/*  Map canvas */
 #map_canvas {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
}
/*  Textual directions frame */
 #directionsPanel {
    float:right;
    display: none;
    width:29%;
    height: 700px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Google Directions</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!-- Libaray untuk auto alamat -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
    <!-- Libaray untuk hitung jarak -->
    <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script> -->
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <!-- The controls are in a floating frame near the bottom of map --> <span id="controls">
            <input id="start" placeholder="Alamat Pengirim" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />
            <input id="end" placeholder="Alamat Tujuan" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />            
            <button onclick="showDirectionsPanelandCalculate();return false">
                Hitung Jarak
            </button>            
        </span>

    <!-- Map canvas -->
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <!-- Directions in text -->
    <div id="directionsPanel">
        <button onclick="hideDirectionsPanel();return false;">Hide</button>
    </div>
    <div id="duration">Perkiraan Waktu:</div>
    <div id="distance">Jarak:</div>
    <div id="ongkos">Ongkos Antar:</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you are missing the imported javascript library list

Comment: sorry, this is the first time for me to ask in stackoverflow

Comment: There is not problem in loading the libraries. You are missing something else in your code. Please use chrome or mozilla debugger to find out the problem. I am adding an example from google which Uses both libraries. Check it out here http://jsbin.com/fepisositinu/1

Comment: Thank you Aks, I just add code snippet to my question. Yes I found error in chrome debuger, but I think it came from google map library. I still dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to debug your code with javascript log.
And I think your problem is on your custom function called calcRoute(start, end)

I try to pass the variable directly without function parameter to be something like below

```
function calcRoute() 
{
    var doStart = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var doFinish = document.getElementById('end').value;

    var request = {
        origin: doStart,
        destination: doFinish,
        provideRouteAlternatives: true,
        avoidHighways: true,
        avoidTolls: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            // Resize the map canvas to accomodate
            // the textual directions panel
            map_canvas.style.width = '70%';
            directionsPanel.style.display = 'inline';
            // Request map resize.
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

            // display the directions
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            // Display the distance:
            document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + " Meter";

            // Display the duration:
            document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " Detik";
```

And also I did some modification for this function

```
function showDirectionsPanelandCalculate() 
{
    if (start.value == 0 || end.value == 0) {
        return;
    }
    calcRoute(start.value, end.value);

}
```

Attached for jsfiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/darizkipratama/Leugobu3/)

Comment: Thank you dork for your solution.  This is what I want. Clearly my mistake.  Vote Up!